# deploying xwiki on cloudfoundry

Tags: cloud-foundry

try to deploy latest xwiki (xwiki-enterprise-web-4.1-milestone-2) war file to cloudfoundry (without coupling to MySql database ) and get strange error (in console, whn trying to start xwiki with STS) :

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /var/vcap/data/dea/apps/politic-xwiki-0-4aa67856cdca2e052aea5e0761b23636/tomcat/../tomcat.state (Too many open files)
at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Native Method)
at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:179)
at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:70)
at java.io.PrintWriter.<init>(PrintWriter.java:146)
at com.vmware.appcloud.tomcat.AppCloudLifecycleListener.handleNotification(AppCloudLifecycleListener.java:48)
at javax.management.NotificationBroadcasterSupport.handleNotification(NotificationBroadcasterSupport.java:257)
at javax.management.NotificationBroadcasterSupport$SendNotifJob.run(NotificationBroadcasterSupport.java:322)
at javax.management.NotificationBroadcasterSupport$1.execute(NotificationBroadcasterSupport.java:307)
at javax.management.NotificationBroadcasterSupport.sendNotification(NotificationBroadcasterSupport.java:229)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4767)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:799)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:779)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:601)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory(HostConfig.java:1079)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectories(HostConfig.java:1002)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:506)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1317)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:324)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:142)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1065)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:840)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1057)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:463)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:525)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:754)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:595)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:289)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:414)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The too many open files issue has been raised before on the Cloud Foundry [forums](http://support.cloudfoundry.com/entries/21149021-too-many-open-files).

I have worked around this before (on my Micro Cloud Foundry instance) using the approach outlined [here](http://mdahlman.wordpress.com/).

You need to edit /var/vcap/packages/dea/dea/lib/dea/agent.rb to increase the open file limit. You can do this as described by Martin Englund on his forum [post](http://support.cloudfoundry.com/entries/21042938-mcf-1-2-0-configuration-error-s). Obviously you can't do this on CloudFoundry.com.

Hope this helps.